# How to create a WSP from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2019, wsp

I'm new to Sharepoint and Visual Studio. I want to understand which is the proper way to create a WSP using Visual Studio.

The WSP must have this content:

- Folder *ISAPI* which contains **service.svc** file;
- **manifest.xml** file;
- **myLibrary.ddl** file;

Which type of project should I create in Visual Studio to have this output? Which are the various steps to create this file in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

You need create farm solution.

[Custom CF DEMO1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/54f565ee-de39-4967-a640-84afb684ca79/wcf-service-the-remote-server-returned-an-unexpected-response-413-request-entity-too-large?forum=sharepointdevelopment) [Custom CF DEMO2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24194.sharepoint-2013-create-a-custom-wcf-rest-service-hosted-in-sharepoint-and-deployed-in-a-wsp.aspx)

Publish when you ready to deploy your solution(VS2017 in my local, VS2019 should be similar).

[image]